# Capybara Selenium click_link: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I'm using Capybara 2.1.0 and Selenium-Webkit 2.38.0 gems to test a Rails 3.2.13 app.

I have the following test:

```
visit my_favorite_path
click_link_or_button 'Share'
page.should have_link 'Send Email'
click_link_or_button 'Send Email'
last_email.should be_present
```

Which is failing on the second "click_link_or_button" with the following (very opaque) error:

```
Failure/Error: click_link_or_button 'Send Email'
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass
```

I get the same error when I replace the offending line with `click_link 'Send Email'` or `first(:link, 'Send Email').click`.

What could be the problem here? The third line of the test passes, seemingly confirming that the link exists, but then trying to click the link fails with this very unhelpful error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, silly me, I forgot to include `js: true` for the test, which seems to have fixed the problem:

```
it 'should send an email when I ask it to', js: true do
  visit my_favorite_path
  click_link_or_button 'Share'
  page.should have_link 'Send Email'
  click_link_or_button 'Send Email'
  last_email.should be_present
end
```

I would really prefer to just delete this question, but it seems I can't anymore. Anyways, maybe it will be helpful to someone else who finds this.

Comment: Not a good idea to delete questions; i solved my problem using your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
click_button "Send Email"
```

Or may be some validation fails check your model and controller code. where start_with is used.

Comment: `grep -r 'start_with?' *` in my app's root gets nothing, and its not a button, its actually a link (`<a>`), so `click_button` won't work